# 'str' object is not callable error even i dont have string yet

Tags: python

I'm very new to python. I was trying to code a simple encryption program. This is my code:

```
import random
z = input("Type the text that you want to encrypt!")
c = random.randint(2, 26) #random number between 2 - 26
if c == 2:
   x = "b"

elif c == 3:
   x = "c"

elif c == 4:
   x = "d"   

elif c == 5:
   x = "e"

elif c == 6:
   x = "f"

elif c == 7:
   x = "g"

elif c == 8:
   x = "h"

elif c == 9:
   x = "i"

elif c == 10:
   x = "j"

elif c == 11:
   x = "k"

elif c == 12:
   x = "l"

elif c == 13:
   x = "m"

elif c == 14:
   x = "n"


elif c == 15:
   x = "o"

elif c == 16:
   x = "p"

elif c == 17:
   x = "q"


elif c == 18:
   x = "r"

elif c == 19:
   x = "s"


elif c == 20:
   x = "t"


elif c == 21:
   x = "u"


elif c == 22:
   x = "v"


elif c == 23:
   x = "w"


elif c == 24:
   x = "x"


elif c == 25:
   x = "y"


elif c == 26:
   x = "z"

d = "We recommended..."
print("then type some encrypting char")
print(d + x)
before_b = input(":")

if before_b == "a" :
  print("Are you serious???")
  b1 = "a"
  b2 = "b"
  b3 = "c"
  b4 = "d"
  b5 = "e"
  b6 = "f"
  b7 = "g"
  b8 = "h"
  b9 = "i"
  b10 = "j"
  b11 = "k"
  b12 = "l"
  b13 = "m"
  b14 = "n"
  b15 = "o"
  b16 = "p"
  b17 = "q"
  b18 = "r"
  b19 = "s"
  b20 = "t"
  b21 = "u"
  b22 = "v"
  b23 = "w"
  b24 = "x"
  b25 = "y"
  b26 = "z"


z = (z.replace("a", b1))
z = (z.replace("b", b2))
z = (z.replace("c", b3))
z = (z.replace("d", b4))
z = (z.replace("e", b5))
z = (z.replace("f", b6))
z = (z.replace("g", b7))
z = (z.replace("h", b8))
z = (z.replace("i", b9))
z = (z.replace("j", b10))
z = (z.replace("k", b11))
z = (z.replace("l", b12))
z = (z.replace("m", b13))
z = (z.replace("n", b14))
z = (z.replace("o", b15))
z = (z.replace("p", b16))
z = (z.replace("q", b17))
z = (z.replace("r", b18))
z = (z.replace("s", b19))
z = (z.replace("t", b20))
z = (z.replace("u", b21))
z = (z.replace("v", b22))
z = (z.replace("w", b23))
z = (z.replace("x", b24))
z = (z.replace("y", b25))
z = (z.replace("z", b26))

e = "Text encrypted! : "
f = "Encrypting char : "
print(e + z)
print(f + before_b)
```

(dont ask why it so looooooonngggg idk how to short them :p) then google colab throw me this :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-91cda9e0e486> in <module>()
    114 
    115 d = "We recommended..."
--> 116 print("then type some encrypting char")
    117 print(d + x)
    118 before_b = input(":")

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can someone help explain to me why it calls an error on print, and how to fix it?

edit#1 : pycharm can run it but not for google colab

Comment: It looks like you have assigned a _variable_ to `print`?

Comment: Restart the kernel then run above code again.

Comment: This is beside the point, but I strongly recommend learning about lists and loops so you don't have to write all of your code dozens of times. I don't think this code reproduces the problem though, which is usually caused by `str = "something"` somewhere in the code, then later on trying to use the builtin function `str(42)` which will raise the TypeError you showed.

Comment: About shortening, use chr to convert ascii int to char like chr(97) = 'a' and ord to convert char to ascii int ord('a')=97

Answer (score 1):

```py
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Is raised on print statement when print is assigned to a variable like

```py
>>> print = "hello"
>>> print("Hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Make sure you are not doing this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

this error  is raised when you try to call a string as a function. To solve this error, make sure you do not use “str” as a variable

Comment: ```'str' object is not callable``` is raised when ```print``` is used

Comment: anyway when i run the above code in google collab i get no errors